# Grepping for the latest versions of software on a Linux server

Tags: linux, bash, grep

OK, I am finding it hard to get my head around this. Can someone help me with the logic?

I have a few Linux Servers with various software installed. I need to know the latest version of the software.

So I `rpm -qa | grep  name | sort -n`

and get:

```
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.1.0.0-3_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.2.0.5-2_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.3.2.1-2_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.4.2.0-1_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.5.0.2-1_es3.0

name_componentB-9.0.2.1.0-1_es3.0_es4.0
name_componentB-9.0.3.0.1-1_es3.0_es4.0
name_componentB-9.0.4.0.0-1_es3.0_es4.0
```

Now I need to output to a file the latest version of the various different software.
The constant here is "name" and the rest changes until "-"

The file outputted I would like to be like this:

```
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.5.0.2-1_es3.0
name_componentB-9.0.4.0.0-1_es3.0_es4.0
```

and so on for all the software.

Comment: How exactly did you manage to get multiple versions of the same package in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the versions are sorted and that a newline occurs between softwares (just like in your example) you can use sed to get all the lines *before* a newline:

```
blackbear@blackbear-notebook:~$ cat test
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.1.0.0-3_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.2.0.5-2_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.3.2.1-2_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.4.2.0-1_es3.0
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.5.0.2-1_es3.0

name_componentB-9.0.2.1.0-1_es3.0_es4.0
name_componentB-9.0.3.0.1-1_es3.0_es4.0
name_componentB-9.0.4.0.0-1_es3.0_es4.0

blackbear@blackbear-notebook:~$ sed -n '/^$/{g;1!p;};h' < test
name_componentA_patch-9.10.9.5.0.2-1_es3.0
name_componentB-9.0.4.0.0-1_es3.0_es4.0
blackbear@blackbear-notebook:~$
```

Comment: Sorry, but can't help nit-picking: the data presented in the question was from a `grep` pipeline.  Do you think that it'd contain blank lines?

Comment: @devnull it might be, I don't really know. If there is this works ;)

Comment: Sort of works. If I pipe grep through `awk -F: '{if(f!=$1)print ""; f=$1; print $0;}'` I get the spaces but the sed command still outputs the same. No individual software is presented.

Comment: Actually it does work if `grep` outputs the data like in @BlackBear example. That means `grep` needs to sort the software in groups and add a space!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but if you have multiple versions of things on a single server, I highly recommend you use the "alternatives" command to manage them.

If you are using alternatives, then the /etc/alternatives directory will have all the links, and /var/lib/alternatives will contain all the information about the different versions of software so managed.